# Hadoop Adding third node gives error

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I am a Hadoop/Pig beginner.

I have 3 nodes in the hadoop cluster. I have Namenode and secondary namenode and job tracker in one of the machine, Data node and task tracker in other two machines. 
All the 3 nodes are separate physical machines.

When I run the sample map reduce example on a 2 node cluster, it works fine. However when i add the third node, it gives me the following error.

> 740514, op: MAPRED_SHUFFLE, cliID:
>   attempt_201206271903_0002_m_000000_0, duration: 37426656 2012-06-27
>   19:13:20,458 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker:
>   getMapOutput(attempt_201206271903_0002_m_000001_0,0) failed :
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find
>   taskTracker/airavat/jobcache/job_201206271903_0002/attempt_201206271903_0002_m_000001_0/output/file.out.index
>   in any of the configured local directories
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathToRead(LocalDirAllocator.java:429)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathToRead(LocalDirAllocator.java:160)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$MapOutputServlet.doGet(TaskTracker.java:3857)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter.doFilter(HttpServer.java:835)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>       at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
>       at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
>
> 2012-06-27 19:13:20,458 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker:
>   Unknown child with bad map output:
>   attempt_201206271903_0002_m_000001_0. Ignored.

I have followed the instructions http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly solution to your problem, but I can give you a checklist to verify somehow. Hope this helps.

1. Have you started the dfs and mapred daemon on the newly added node?
2. Have you added the third node in the slave config file?
3. Check the data path you specified in the hdfs-site file, make sure the third node can write data there.